# Show image gallery in camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm working on a feature where the user can take a picture and choose from the gallery. This is basically where it starts and goes on to save the images in db.

```
 private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }
```

However, I want to make the user experience better. I want to skip the dialog where the user selects one of the options (from gallery or camera) and instead show the gallery in camera intent. Something similar to this:

[image]

I hope you get my point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all image

```js
public List<File> getAllShownImagesPath(Context context) {
        //get all images
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = null;
        final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Specify the provider
                        columns, // The columns we're interested in
                        null, // A WHERE-filter query
                        null, // The arguments for the filter-query
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
                );

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int r = 0; r < cursor.getCount(); r++, cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int i = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));
                //int l = cursor.getString(1).length();
                final int image_path_col = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (i > 0) {
                    f = new File(cursor.getString(image_path_col));
                    if (f.length() > 0) {
                        result.add(f);
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

2. Add all image into recyclerview or listview

Comment: How can I show the list of images in camera intent?

Comment: You should custom layout for camera with recyclerview contain all images, examples about custom camera layout: stackoverflow.com/questions/8543244/custom-camera-android